# Apple Pay Sandbox adding AMEX fails

Tags: applepay

Using the apple pay sandbox on my iphone, I continue to get

Could Not Add Card
Try again later or contact your card
issuer for more information.
Add a Card Later
Try Again

I have tested with every AMEX card listed:
https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/

I was able to add Discover, Mastercard, VISA without issue.

My sandbox account is bound to USA, however I am currently testing from Costa Rica.  My phone was purchased and registered in the USA.

I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

We are running into the same issue. Have not found an answer in the traditional sense, however wanted to share the finding that this appears to be a known issue.

Here are two links to unrelated Apple discussions about the matter:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8555293
- https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/99265